# Excel-Addin with visible form

Tags: windows, winforms, excel, add-in

I have a query on the usage of windows form in excel add-in, application level.

Objective Statement: 
Display customized windows form control, similar to a way a chart is being inserted into excel

1. Custom Pane
   I have tried custom pane add-in but it seems to be on a entire workbook level, i need something on a worksheet level
2. Task Pane
   I can't seem to use the task pane in application add-in for excel
3. Windows Form Control
   When I click on a cell in excel i will lose focus to the windows form, i will need the windows to be together with the worksheet, but i can't use showdialog.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 5):

*From your answer it is hard for me to figure out if you we are looking at a code solution here or something more high level, so I am going to assume that you are looking for a code solution, please correct me if I am wrong.*

Have you considered using an OLE object or ActiveX?

There is an example from Microsoft here, [how to develop an ActiveX control](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/csactivex-b86194f8). (Here is some other [walkthrough](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2011/12/05/how-to-develop-and-deploy-activex-control-in-c/) that I found helpful).

Just to give you a hint how it (the example mentioned above) looks like, here is the screenshot of the compiled example that I added onto the excel sheet:

[image: activex in excel example]

ActiveX control can be added both [manually](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-or-register-an-activex-control-8fc743a1-e72b-4b55-af3a-85d326e53918?ocmsassetID=HP010236683&CorrelationId=ab7926d1-707e-4c8d-946c-5552755fe521&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), or by [code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.OLEObjects.Add), so I could imagine that you could also provide a [COM Excel Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-excel?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019) that would add some buttons onto the ribbon, that when pressed, would add the desired controls onto the sheet.